# Freeze/lock an image on xlsx sheet using apache.poi

Tags: java, xssf, xsl-stylesheet

I'm creating an xlsx using Apache.POI and inserting a logo at the top,how do I freeze or lock the images so that it cant be changed once the xlsx is downloaded.

```
      int numberOfSheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
            for(int i=0;i<numberOfSheets;i++)
            {
                XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

                try {
                    //insert a logo
                    String location = "C:/Git/cc/src/main/resources/logo/VCC_logo.jpg"; // hard coded for testing
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(location);
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                    int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
                    is.close();
                    // Create Winner sheet

                    CreationHelper creationHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
                    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();


                    ClientAnchor anchor = 
                    creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
                    anchor.setCol1(0);
                    anchor.setRow1(0);
                    Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
                    pict.resize(2.5,2.5);
                    pict.getImageDimension().setSize(3.0,3.0);
                    sheet.createFreezePane(0,3);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw  new nException("Problem in reading VCC_logo.jpg");
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    throw  new Exception("Problem in reading VCC_logo.jpg");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your logo starts at row `i` and column `j`. You could use the API [`createFreezePane`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createFreezePane(int,%20int)) like :

`Sheet.createFreezePane( i, j );`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it is freezing the rows and images on that pane is still movable in the sheet. I have 2 sheets on xlsx, when I open the xlsx the images is locked cant move, but as soon as I go to 2nd sheet and try to move the image it starts moving for 1st sheet as well.

Comment: you have to call createFreezePane on the sheet you want to freeze. Please post the code in the question to get better help.

Comment: Where are you calling createFreezePane ?